# to find number of groups in regex in scala

Tags: regex, scala

In my Scala code ,there is user defined function ,which takes a source string and regular expression .Number of group present in regex should dynamically split the value in string in different variable.
For example

`SPLIT("REGEX   90",'(\w+)\s+(\d+)')`

should return a List[String] with value in group,So value return in 
List will be

`List("REGEX","90")`

I can count number of group present in regex then split thing but this will be have very complex logic.I beleive scala must have a built in function which can dynamically group regex matching value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use excellent Scala regex support.

First define a regex:

```
scala> val regex = """(\w+)\s+(\d+)""".r
regex: scala.util.matching.Regex = (\w+)\s+(\d+)
```

If you just want to capture 2 groups use pattern matching:

```
scala> "REGEX   90" match { case regex(word, number) => s"word: $word, number: $number" }
res2: String = word: REGEX, number: 90
```

If you want all matched groups in a List you need to get subgroups `sub` of the first group `m` that implicitly exists there and matches your entire string:

```
 (for { m <- regex findAllMatchIn "REGEX   90"; sub <- m subgroups } yield sub) toList
res3: List[String] = List(REGEX, 90)
```

If you want to simplify a bit and don't care about matching a number, then:

```
scala> (for { words <- """\w+""".r findAllIn "REGEX   90" } yield words) toList
res4: List[String] = List(REGEX, 90)
```

Check the [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex) if you need more examples or want to look at other available methods.

Comment: I just started loving scala